# How to add milestone in MS Project server 2013?

Tags: ms-project-2013

I have MS Project server 2013 integrated with SharePoint 2013. I have created PWA site and in task page I want to add milestone as we do in MS Project professional 2013 but I don't see any options, any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is PWA site?

Comment: Project web app site

Answer (score 1):

Just set the task to 0 duration.  If your permissions allow this operation, that will change it to a milestone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic permission issue. You probably have been granted as "**Team member** only, therefore your actions are limited to:

- Add a task to your task status
- Assigning a task to another resource
- Print a view
- Create, view, and link project issues and risks
- Approve or reject task updates
- Get e-mail alerts or reminders when tasks change

If you are the one creating / removing tasks and milestones, you should be granted a **Project Manager** role